# Scroll for modal bootstrap

Tags: html, jquery, css

[Scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dELO.jpg)

This is the class code and the problem for scroll in desktop.
At mobile work but in desktop not apper scroll tab

Answer (score 1):

[Modal scrollable](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/modal/)

```html
<!-- Scrollable modal -->
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable">
  ...
</div>
```